# Grep / awk, match exact string

Tags: awk, grep

I need to find the ID of some container docker, but some containers have similar names:

```
$ docker images

REPOSITORY       TAG                 IMAGE ID            
app-node         latest              620350b79c5a        
app-node-temp    latest              461c5143a985
```

If I run:

```
$ docker images | grep -w app-node-temp | awk -e '{print $3}'

461c5143a985
```

If I run instead:

```
$ docker images | grep -w app-node | awk -e '{print $3}'

620350b79c5a
461c5143a985
```

How can I match the exact name?

Comment: Dashes are considered non-word characters.  In context, `grep '^app-node[[:space:]]'` would work.  Of course, `grep` | `awk` is an anti-pattern most of the time: `docker images | awk '/^app-node[[:space:]]/ { print $3 }'` would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dashes are considered non-word characters, so `grep -w` won't work when the difference is marked by a dash.

In context, `grep '^app-node[[:space:]]'` would work.  It looks for the required name followed by a space.

Of course, `grep` | `awk` is an anti-pattern most of the time; it would be better to use:

```
docker images | awk '/^app-node[[:space:]]/ { print $3 }'
```

Or, an easier solution with `awk` again uses equality — as suggested by [Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37119260/15168):

```
for server in app-node app-node-temp
do
    docker images | awk -v server="$server" '$1 == server { print $3 }'
    …
done
```

If running `docker images` is too expensive, you can run it once and capture the output in a file and then scan the file.  This shows how to pass a shell variable into the `awk` script.

The chances are the pipeline would be run to capture the container's image ID information:

```
image_id=$(docker images | awk -v server="$server" '$1 == server { print $3 }')
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd say just use awk with exact string matching:

```
docker images | awk '$1 == "app-node" { print $3 }'
```